# Convert method to Delegate?

Tags: .net, delegates, c#-4.0

I want to call for example `TryDo.Do(MessageBox.Show(""), null);`

how can I do that??

```
using System;

namespace TryCatchHandlers
{
    public static class TryDo
    {
        public static CallResult Do(Delegate action, params object[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                return new CallResult (action.DynamicInvoke(args), action.Method.ReturnType, true);
            }
            catch
            {
                return new CallResult(null, null, false);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CallResult
    {
        public CallResult() { }

        internal CallResult(object result, Type resultType, bool isSuccessful)
        {
            Result = result;
            ResultType = resultType;
            IsSuccessful = isSuccessful;
        }
        public object Result { get; private set; }
        public Type ResultType { get; private set; }
        public bool IsSuccessful { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DynamicInvoke` is slow.

Comment: @slaks: what can I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code *calls `MessageBox.Show`*, then tries to pass the result to `TryDo`.
Since `MessageBox.Show` doesn't return a `Delegate`, that won't work.

Instead, you should pass the `Show` method itself, along with a parameter:

```
TryDo.Do(new Func<string, DialogResult>(MessageBox.Show), "");
```

Alternatively, you can pass an anonymous method that calls the function:

```
TryDo.Do(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("")));
```

Note that your function will perform faster if you make generic overloads that take `Func`s and `Action`s instead of taking a `Delegate` and calling `DynamicInvoke`.

Comment: @slaks: I like `TryDo.Do(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("")));` method, how should I change `TryDo.Do()` to just get a function and run it?

Comment: I want to call something like `TryDo.Do(Foo, args[]);`

Comment: @HPT: If you make overloads that take specific delegates, C# will implicitly infer the delegate type.

Comment: @slaks: so you mean I write `Do(Action)`, `Do(Action<in T1>)`, `Do(Action<inT1, in T2>)`, .... and , `Do(Func<out Tresult>)`, `Do(Func<in T1, out Tresult>)`, `Do(Func<in T1, in T2, out Tresult>)`, ... ??

Comment: @HPT: Yes, except without the `in` and `out`, and with generic parameters in the method.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `MessageBox.Show("")` is a method call, not a delegate, so

```
TryDo.Do(MessageBox.Show(""),null);
```

actually tries to call `TryDo.Do` with the result of the `MessageBox.Show` call.

You actually need to transfer a delegate that contains the method you are trying to call, because

```
TryDo.Do(MessageBox.Show,null);
```

will also fail, with an error that a Method cannot be cast as delegate.
The simplest way to create a delegate from a method is to use the `Func<..>` and `Action<...>` generic delegates (Func for those methods that return something, Action for those that are void), like this:

```
var myDelegate = new Func<string, DialogResult>(MessageBox.Show);
TryDo.Do(myDelegate, null)
```

Comment: Exactly my point, you are passing the result of the method invocation, instead of the method itself (MessageBox.Show returns DialogResult)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Delegate d = (Action)delegate { MessageBox.Show(""); };
TryDo.Do(d, null);
```